# Repeating values in listview after back press

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity, listadapter

I have an application it have two activities. When press a button in the main activity, it shows customized listview, then I press hard back button and go to the main page of my application.

Then I again press the same button and go to the listview it shows the repeated values in the listview.

Any one have any sloution please???

```
        CookList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        url = new URI(cookUri);
        List<DataModels> list1 = new ArrayList<DataModels>();
        CookListServer cookServer = new CookListServer();
        StringBuilder responseString =  cookServer.CookConnect(url, "hi");
        System.out.println("responseString---------"+responseString);

        for(int i=0; i< itemId.size(); i++){
            HashMap<String, String> Cook = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Cook.put("ItemId", itemId.get(i));
            System.out.println("itemId--------"+itemId.get(i));
            Cook.put("ItemName", itemName.get(i));
            Cook.put("ItemQty", itemQty.get(i));
            CookList.add(Cook);
            list1.add(get(i));
        }
        adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(context, CookList, R.layout.cooklist_item, list1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

private DataModels get(int s) {
    return new DataModels(s);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}



// Adapter to list the Albums
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> implements SectionIndexer {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> values;
    List<DataModels> modellist;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> values, int layout, List<DataModels> modellist) {
        super(context, R.layout.cooklist_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.modellist = modellist;
    }

    private final class ViewHolder {
        public TextView Nametext;
        public TextView Qntytext;
        public Button prepareButton;
    }

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = null;
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            if (mLayoutInflater == null) {
                mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            }

            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cooklist_item, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.Nametext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.Qntytext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            viewHolder.prepareButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prepareButton1);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            ((ViewHolder) convertView.getTag()).prepareButton.setTag(modellist.get(position));
        }

        final HashMap<String, String> cooklist = values.get(position);
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        final String ItemId = cooklist.get("ItemId");
        final String ItemName = cooklist.get("ItemName");
        final String ItemQty = cooklist.get("ItemQty");

        System.out.println("ItemId---------"+ItemId);
        System.out.println("ItemName---------"+ItemName);
        System.out.println("ItemQty---------"+ItemQty);

        holder.Nametext.setText(ItemName);

        holder.Qntytext.setText(ItemQty);

        registerForContextMenu(convertView);


        holder.prepareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DataModels element = (DataModels) viewHolder.prepareButton.getTag();
                holder.prepareButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

Thanks...

Comment: Can you give us some code and/or examples of what happens?

Comment: i think you are adding elements to the arrayadapter (if you are using any ) in the onresume() . Once post your first and second activities

Comment: As I can guess you are initializing once again values in list view if yes you should do it in different place or clean list view before each init.

Comment: @Robert Sorry, I can't get you....

Comment: At which method (onCreate, onRestart...) you are calling the try catch block?

Comment: @Robert onCreate method use a try catch block but its for handling http section...

Comment: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/  try to do it in this way

Comment: I had same problem but long long time ago as I good remember there was a problem with custom ArrayAdater - the place where objects was stored was not cleaned and values was added at the end once again. You can also try to test you case by doing it multiple time and check that is it adding it more than two times.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17869/discussion-between-user4232-and-robert)

Comment: hi all i got a solution for it. ie, at onDestroy function i cleared all the ArrayList<String> (itemId,itemName,itemQty). Now it is working correctly. Thanks all for helping me in this problem... Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    itemId.clear();
    itemName.clear();
    itemQty.clear();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Thanks....

Comment: Invocation of a superclass constructor must be the first line in the subclass constructor.